# How to reduce Trees Maximum entries in a git repo?

Tags: git, performance, github, slowdown

My repo became very slow and to debug it I installed git-sizer.

I see from git-sizer output:

```
| Biggest objects              |           |                                |
| * Commits                    |           |                                |
|   * Maximum size         [1] |   734 B   |                                |
|   * Maximum parents      [2] |     2     |                                |
| * Trees                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum entries      [3] |  33.1 k   | !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! |
| * Blobs                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum size         [4] |  90.5 MiB | *********                      |

| Biggest checkouts            |           |                                |
| * Number of directories  [5] |  2.30 k   | *                              |
| * Maximum path depth     [6] |     8     |                                |
| * Maximum path length    [6] |   156 B   | *                              |
| * Number of files        [5] |   348 k   | ****                           |
```

For my repo "Maximum entries" is reaching limit as shown "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!".

But the number of files is not that bad "****".

So whats happening here?

Is there a way I can reduce the "Maximum entries" for my git repo?

I have already tried:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now


git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags

rm -rf .git/refs/original/

git fetch
git reset origin/main --hard
```

Comment: It means you have a large tree (i.e. likely a directory containing a large number of files), pruning won't help. You'll likely need to reorganize your files and possibly rewrite history if you don't want to store the old large tree.

Comment: @Hasturkun how to rewrite history for a directory

Comment: Probably easiest to use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), but you should be aware that rewriting history is risky for a shared/public repository, so rewrite with care. I highly recommend reading its documentation through.